# Converting 2 columns of names into 4 columns of names using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file that consists of two columns: `last_name`, `first_name`. The list is sorted by years of experience. I would like to create an new Excel file (or text file) that prints the names two-by-two.

```py
Last       First
Smith      Joe
Jones      Mary
Johnson    Ken 
etc
```

and converts it to

```py
Smith      Joe           Jones       Mary
Johnson    Ken           etc.
```

effectively printing every other name on the same row as the name above.

I have reached the point where the names can be printed into a single set of columns, but I can't move every other name to adjacent columns.

Thanks

Comment: can you add the code you have so far, seems like you're almost there, just a few modifications needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Yes, my question has been answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
result = pd.concat([df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True),
           df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)], 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
      Last First   Last First
0    Smith   Joe  Jones  Mary
1  Johnson   Ken    etc  None
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solved my problem completely.